# Remove repository from `git fetch --all` that no longer exists

Tags: git, github

My apologies if there's already an answer to this, however, I've been unsuccessful in trying to resolve this non-blocking issue. I thought the solution would involve something with using Git's `prune` flag, but I haven't been able to get it to work. For my organization, I had set up my `git fetch --all` flag to fetch multiple remotes. One member left recently and now the following occurs:

```
(~~~~~) ~~~-12345:~~~~~ ~~~~~~$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Fetching name1
Fetching name2
Fetching name3
Fetching name4
Fetching name5
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch name5
Fetching name6
...
```

As `name6` no longer exists, I would like to modify this command such that it no longer attempts to pull it. Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm assuming the answer is going to be incredibly straightforward and I'll be doing quite the facepalm, but I find it likely that others have had this problem and whatever the solution is it could be helpful for some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove a remote with

```
git remote rm <remote>
```

In your example, `git remote rm name5`.

You can list all remotes before and after this command using `git remote -v` to verify.

Comment: To clarify, the solution isn't to modify the fetch command. It's to update your Git config file appropriately.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for the clarification - that's so simple. At least my expectation of the facepalm was accurate! 